# Complicated situation in the simplex method?

Tags: simplex

I am having a problem with the simplex method and here is my tableau section

$$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
x1 & x2 & x3  & x4                           & x5 & x6 & x7 & s1 & s2 & s3 & s4 & s5 & s6 & s7 & s8 & s9 & s10 & RHS \\ \hline
0  & 0  & -1  & 1                            & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 1  & -1 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 1   & 9   \\ \hline
{Other\ rows}                                                                                    \\ \hline
0  & 0  & -1  & 1                            & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 1  & 0   & 9   \\ \hline
{Other\ rows}                                                                                    \\ \hline
20 & 0  & -10 & -15 ( most\ negative) & {Unimportant \ values}                              \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
In this case I took 9 and divided by 1 in  the pivot column (col x4 since -15 is the most negative value). And now It is quite difficult to decide which row is the pivot row because 9/1 in row 1 and row 3 is now equal.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Just take one of the two. In both cases the objective will raise about 15/9.

Comment: one of the two row result in a different Objective function are there any explanation for this ?

Comment: No, at the end the optimal value of the objective function should be the same.